# why is my memory footprint blowing up in this greedy approach to tsp?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, np-complete

I have an assignment to use a greedy approach to satisfy TSP. The problem has 33708 cities. because I had a lot of helpful tools for this from the previous assignment, I decided to reuse that approach and precompute the distances.

so that is barely more than half a billion entries (33708  choose 2), each comfortably fitting in a float32. The x and y coordinates, likewise, are numbers $|n| < 10000 $ with no more than 4 decimal places.

My python for the same was:

```py
def get_distance(left, right):
  """ return the euclidean distance between tuples left and right, which are coordinates"""
  return ((left[0] - right[0]) ** 2 + (left[1] - right[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5

# precompute all distances
distances = {}
for i in range(len(cities)):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(cities)):
    d = get_distance(cities[i], cities[j])
    distances[frozenset((i, j)))] = d
```

and I expected this to occupy (3 * 32b) * 568m ≈ 6.7 gigabytes of memory. But in fact, watching the live runtime in my jupyter notebook, it appears to be shooting past even 35GB.  (442s and counting) I had to kill it as I was well into my swap space and it slowed down a lot. Anyone know why this is so surprisingly large?

update: trying again with `tuple(sorted((i,j)))` -- but already at 110s it is 15GB and counting

### sizes

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = frozenset((1,2))
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
216
>>> sys.getsizeof(tuple(sorted((1,2))))
56
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
28
```

is there anything like float32 and int16 in python?? -- ans: numpy has them

### updated attempt:

```
from numpy import float32, int16
from itertools import combinations
import sys

def get_distance(left, right):
  """ return the euclidean distance between tuples left and right, which are coordinates"""
  return float32(((left[0] - right[0]) ** 2 + (left[1] - right[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5)

# precompute all distances
distances = {}
for i, j in combinations(range(len(cities)), 2):
    distances[tuple(sorted((int16(i), int16(j))))] = get_distance(cities[i], cities[j])

print(sys.getsizeof(distances))
```

observed sizes:

- with `cities = cities[:2]` : 232
- with `cities = cities[:3]` : also 232
- with `cities = cities[:10]` : 2272
- with `cities = cities[:100]` : 147552
- with `cities = cities[:1000]` : 20971608 (20MB)
- with `cities = cities[:10000]` : 2684354656 (2.6GB)

note the growth rate does not scale with the data even as we approach 50 million entries ie 10000 choose 2 (10% of the total size of the data):

- 2684354656/(1000 choose 2 / 100 choose 2 * 20971608) ≈ 1.27
- 20971608/(1000 choose 2 / 100 choose 2 * 147552) ≈ 1.4

I decided to halt my attempt at the full cities list, as my OS snapshot of the memory grew to well over 30GB and I was going to swap. This means that, even if the final object ends up that big, the amount of memory the notebook is requiring is much larger still.

Comment: What's the 3 * 32b?

Comment: 1x32b is the distance. 2 more are the x and y coordinates. (updated the problem description). at the point of assignment, these are `d`, `i` and `j`.

Comment: ooh that is true. i and j are integers ... I think I need types that allow me to specify the byte size of the values I am tracking, to make this efficient.

Comment: Those probably take about 30 bytes each. And then you have the sets, and the dictionary structure.

Comment: Try for example `sys.getsizeof(frozenset((1, 2)))`.

Comment: regards the dictionary structure, I should be able to ignore the list overhead because I have half a billion entries, the data should instead bound the size. that is the distance ´d´and the size of the keys (it should only go to a hash if the size of the keys is larger than then hash, right?)

Comment: I wish I could vote you up twice for that last comment. adding some details to the bottom of the post

Comment: Compared to the *actual* key/value object footprints, yes, the dictionary footprint is probably insignificant. But it's larger than your initial thought. For example, `sys.getsizeof(dict.fromkeys(range(10**6))) / 1e6` gives me `41.943136`, so about 42 bytes of dictionary footprint per item.

Comment: You could use `float`, I think that's the number type with the smallest footprint. Or [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), if that's not too far away from those "tools" you'd like to reuse. Or instead of an material dict, create a virtual one that only computes values on the fly when requested.

Comment: The memory for all the `i` and `j` objects could be reduced a lot by reusing the same objects, for example not having many objects all with the same value 3141. Like with `for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(cities)), 2):`. But the sets/tuples/dictionary would still cost a lot anyway.

Comment: you sir deserve the answer, please post that hint. I think I can maybe do it now.. I'm at 2.6GB for the first 10000 entries  (that should work out to roughly 30gb total) and haven't tried further optimizations yet

Comment: Not sure what I could write. The question asks why it's so large and then pretty much answers itself already, as half a billion times 216 bytes is a lot. Feel free to write an answer yourself.

Comment: "the growth rate does not scale with the data" - I'd say it does, it just doesn't resize for every single new item. Try scaling by factor 2 instead of 10, then you have a better chance for equal load factors.

Comment: what I meant to say is that it does not scale linearly.

Comment: That's what I thought you meant, and I disagree.

Comment: [Demo](https://tio.run/##JYzBCoMwEETvfsXcTEQstQiloP/S1tWG4iZs9pL@fBp1bm/fzoSkH8@3e5Cc3Ra8KGKKVbV4AcEx5MkrmevQoh/so0IJY0SPpgEdOBec3Vu7Rfz2pRTN2WFrDx/dj8pLme1W0p38YubTBXGshlvUTmmLwDihbo/KZb@@klJEIMHua5vzHw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python objects have an overhead because of dynamic typing and reference counting. The absolute minimal object `object()` has a size of `16` bytes (on 64 bit machines). `8` byte reference count, `8` bytes type pointer. **No** python object can be smaller than that. `float` and `int` are slightly larger which `24` bytes at least. `list` are at least an array of pointers, which adds an additional `8` bytes. So the small possible memory footprint of a list of half a billion ints is `32 * 500_000_000` ~= 16Gb. `sets` and `dicts` are even larger than that since they store more than just one pointer per element.

Use `numpy` (maybe the stdlib `array` module is already enough).

(Note: The numpy float32 types can't be smaller than 16 bytes either)

Comment: "So the small possible memory footprint of a list of half a billion ints" - Only if they're all different. If you reuse them, as can easily be done here, it's less.

Comment: @KellyBundy Then it is still 8 * 500_000_000 ~= 4GB at least, still more than OP expected. ( I am ignoring the `3 *` as well)

Comment: @KellyBundy And remember, I am just talking about lists. Not about dictionaries of tuples.

Comment: I just want to note that this is largely to me Kelly's answer, but he literally reached out to me or anyone to give it because he didnt feel it is an answer. But I do. I thank you both. (And no, it doesnt appear to get me below 30gb in practice, but that was not a requirement, my understanding was.)